# Install and enable the intl extension (used for validators)

Tags: symfony, osx-mountain-lion, mamp

During the Symfony configuration, it is recommended to install and enable intl extension.
I have followed this tutorial: http://sunny.chotai.uk.com/?p=2.

In the **Terminal**, I wrote this command:

```
sudo port install php54-intl
```

But then I got this message:

```
Warning: The Command Line Tools for Xcode don't appear to be installed;
most ports will likely fail to build.
Warning: See http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.xcode.html
for more information.
--->  Computing dependencies for php54-intlError: Unable to execute port:
can't read "build.cmd": Failed to locate 'make' in path:
'/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin'
or at its MacPorts configuration time location, did you move it?`
```

Why it didn't work and how to solve it. My config is **MAMP 2.1.4** and **OS X 10.8.3**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install XCode and the command line tools within XCode for MacPorts to function.

That's also listed as one of the requirements on the [MacPorts Install Page](http://www.macports.org/install.php#requirements).

Comment: Actually, I've just understoden what you're saying. This small step was what I didn't catch. For those who don't no where to install these command line tools: go to Preferences and then Downloads and you should have a command line tools to install.

I experienced the same issue by attempting to install RVM.